# In nightwatch.js moveToElement() is deprecated. I want to move pointer to a offset and doubleClick on that. How to go forward with this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nightwatch.js

In nightwatch.js moveToElement() method is deprecated. I want to move pointer to a offset and doubleClick on that. how can I implement this ?  I am getting this error on Firefox.

Comment: Can you post your code and also add the error that you are getting ?

Answer (score 0):

The `.moveToElement()` as I can see from the official Nightwatch documentation is not deprecated. You can look here - https://nightwatchjs.org/api/moveToElement.html#apimethod-page.

It accepts three parameters - Selector, X-Offset and Y-Offset. If your browser resolution is fixed then you can use this method without a problem because then the X and Y coordinates of your element won't get changed.

You can write something like:

```
browser
    .moveToElement('div:nth-child(3)', 50, 50)
    .doubleClick()
```

I have written a simple example for moveToElement(), you can check it out here - https://github.com/alapanme/NightwatchJS/blob/master/tests/TC011_keyboardMouseEvents.js

Comment: moveToElement() may not be deprecated but it doesn't work now as it doesn't fit into new W3C protocols, because previously it was working fine on Chrome and Firefox but now its giving error, as all browsers are using these W3C protocols. For now i have put W3C: false in chrome options but i want the permanent solution for both browsers.